# PHP Use Client IP to connect to smtp server

Tags: javascript, php, smtp

We offer the client an interface where he can log in to SMTP server.
The problem is that the connection to SMTP server should be done from the client ip
I tried using curl and fsockopen but without success.
I want to know if you can achieve such a connection, I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: the IP will always be yours

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is no answer to your problem but on serverside you will not be able to open a connection with the client ip!

Even if you are using JS you can only send request which will not work with mail servers!